# Executable bit gone on /etc/grub.d/10_linux

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which is a current version of Ubuntu at the time of writing this question. I am currently on kernel `5.15.0-27-generic`. I only use default (generic) kernels.

### The problem

After a reboot, I noticed that my Grub menu was empty. None of the installed kernels (currently: 1, `5.15.0-27-generic`) were listed.

I was able to repair my system by using a bootable USB and restoring a backup of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

### My findings

I went troubleshooting and I found:

- At the end of each kernel installation or removal, `/usr/sbin/update-grub` is run.
- `update-grub` runs *scripts* in `/etc/grub.d/` to generate the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. The scripts are executed in alphanumerical order.
- *Scripts* being the operative word here, requirements are:

  - Being a valid shell script
  - Starting with `#! /bin/sh`
  - Having an execute bit (`chmod +x`)
- I found that the file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` did **not** have an execute bit (that was unexpected), so it was ignored by `update-grub`. This is the script that is responsible for adding Linux kernels to the Grub menu.

A solution to my issue was to `chmod +x /etc/grub.d/10_linux` and run `update-grub` again.

### My question

Which package, update, whatever,... removed the execute bit from `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`? I definitely did not do this myself. I want to avoid that this ever happens again.

Feel free to ask me additional questions. I'll add requested info. Let's make this a constructive collaborative effort in troubleshooting. If needed, I'll even open an issue report upstream.

### Command outputs

```
$ ls -l /boot/
total 78772
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   260489 apr 14 06:46 config-5.15.0-27-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 jan 30 12:46 efi
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 jul 31 18:04 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63078554 jul 30 14:03 initrd.img-5.15.0-27-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6241791 apr 14 06:46 System.map-5.15.0-27-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 11064224 apr 14 06:47 vmlinuz-5.15.0-27-generic
```

```
$ ls -l /etc/grub.d/
total 156
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 jul 31 20:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 169 root root 12288 jul 30 14:04 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10627 sep  2  2021 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6260 apr 15 23:50 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 18683 apr 15 23:50 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 43031 sep  2  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 14180 apr 15 23:50 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 13369 apr 15 23:50 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1372 apr 15 23:50 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   700 feb 21 01:12 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   214 sep  2  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   215 apr 15 23:50 41_custom
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 jan 30 14:02 backup
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 sep  2  2021 README
```

Comment: The thing is, this is the second time in a few months that this has happened. Which rules out cosmic rays. It is probably one of the many packages I installed because I agree that it cannot be reproduced on clean install. I require debugging steps to identify the offending software.

Comment: I've had this same thing happen a number of times, but I've yet to track down why. Did you ever figure it out? I've just gotten in the habit of triple checking it after anything that runs update-grub via apt executes. My suspicion is `ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings` but I don't have confirmation of it.

Comment: I am not certain, but my suspicion is also with `ubuntustudio-lowlatency`. For whatever it is worth, the issue has no longer occurred since I uninstalled everything related to Ubuntustudio.